# Object particles fly up, move in the wrong direction

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles, cloth-simulation, force-fields

I'm new to Blender and I can't figure out why my particles move into the wrong direction. I made a plane with paper texture and cloth simulation, I use this object as the particle, my emitter is a cube. I want my particles to fly through the screen in front of a green plane. I changed my Z axis gravity to 0 and the Y axis gravity to 10.
[image: gravity]

However, when I start the animation the particles starts moving higher and higher, like the emitter is moving, while its clearly not.
[image: Particles high (I think they really are.)]

I disabled every force other than gravity and wind, I'm using Blender Render, version 2.79b. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What happens if you set the y axis gravity to -10?

Comment: They move downwards. The Y movement is right both times.

Comment: I also tried halo and line particles and they work perfectly, so I think the problem is with my object which I use as particle.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out what caused it. I don't know why (I'm a noob, sorry), but the gravity effector under cloth field weights on the object which I used as a particle caused this. I changed it to 0 and now it works just like I wanted.
[image: Now it works.]

Noice. Anyway, sorry for my stupid question.